# How do we filter out tables and provide for source jdbc connector to fetch data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm aware of providing `table.whitelist` property to fetch data from whitelisted tables.
Now, in our database we need to extract data from tables whose table names are in some format.

For example, my database may contain tables as :-

```
cus_01
emp_01
cus_02
emp_02
```

And need to extract tables which as 01 at end (i.e.,cus_01 and emp_01).

How can I achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide regex for `table.whitelist` or `table.include.list` properties.

For your use case, you can use the following properties to include those tables which end with `01`

```
"table.include.list": "^(Database_name.)(.+01)"
```

Comment: Suppose, in my table now the tables are like :- cust_abc_xyz, cust_01, cust_xyz_abc . I want to fetch abc_xyz and xyz_abc tables ? how to configure that?? Can I pass other format by using comma (,) in table.include.list

Comment: I don't know about adding comma for other format, but I will suggest you regex for your use case it is `^(Database_name.)((.+01)|(.+_abc_xyz)|(.+_xyz_abc))$`